# How to sum the value of previous row with the current row value Teradata

Tags: sum, row, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have a table in Teradata as below

| Record_id | sub_id | amount | seq_no | total_unwind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 0830 | 1.00 | 1 | ? |
| 123 | 0830 | 3.00 | 2 | ? |
| 123 | 0830 | 4.00 | 3 | ? |
| 456 | 0850 | 2.00 | 1 | ? |
| 456 | 0850 | 1.00 | 2 | ? |
| 456 | 0850 | 5.00 | 3 | ? |

I want the sum of amount in total_unwind column by grouping record_id and sub_id, and ordering seq_no.

For eg. for record_id 123 and sub_id 830,

For seq_no 1, total_unwind will be same as amount. Total_unwind=1.00

For seq_no=2, the total_unwind will be 1.00(previous total_unwind)+ 3.00(current amount). Total_unwind=4.00

For seq_no=3, the total_unwind will be 4.00 (previous total_unwind)+ 4.00(current amount). Total_unwind=8.00

The sum should start again for the new set of record_id and sub_id

The output should look like below:

| Record_id | sub_id | amount | seq_no | total_unwind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 0830 | 1.00 | 1 | 1.00 |
| 123 | 0830 | 3.00 | 2 | 4.00 |
| 123 | 0830 | 4.00 | 3 | 8.00 |
| 456 | 0850 | 2.00 | 1 | 2.00 |
| 456 | 0850 | 1.00 | 2 | 3.00 |
| 456 | 0850 | 5.00 | 3 | 8.00 |

I tried the below query in Teradata

```
sel record_id,sub_id,amount,seq_no, sum(amount) over (order by sub_id,SEQ_NO ROWS  UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) as total_unwind from table_name
```

The output for the above query is as below

| Record_id | sub_id | amount | seq_no | total_unwind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 0830 | 1.00 | 1 | 1.00 |
| 123 | 0830 | 3.00 | 2 | 4.00 |
| 123 | 0830 | 4.00 | 3 | 8.00 |
| 456 | 0850 | 2.00 | 1 | 10.00 |
| 456 | 0850 | 1.00 | 2 | 11.00 |
| 456 | 0850 | 5.00 | 3 | 16.00 |

It sums the value continuously till the end which is not needed.
Can someone please help with using group by on record_id,sub_id

Comment: It looks like you want to sum by record_id?  If so, you need to include partition by in your `over` clause  - `sum(amount) over (partition by record_id order by seq_no)`